# Game of Life 1d Array error updating board

Tags: php, jquery, d, q

Hi I am having a lot of trouble trying to get this function to work, I attempted to create an array within the function that takes in the main pointer array's values and edits the values before updating the pointer array by inputting the temporary array back into the pointer.

**My attempt at trying to get the array to transfer properly has not been working as I am getting really strangely large or small values when the board should only have 1's or 0's.**

The print statement is placed in order to check if the array has properly been inputted. I believe the rest of my code should be correct.

```
void updateBoard(int* board, int boardRowSize, int boardColSize) {
    int i,j,sum,k;
    k = boardRowSize * boardColSize;
    int array[k];
    for(i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++){

        for(j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++){
            array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = board[(i * boardColSize) + j];
            printf("%d",array[i * boardColSize + j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
    for(i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++){ 
                sum = 0;
                sum = countLiveNeighbor(board,boardRowSize,boardColSize,i,j);
                if(board[i * boardColSize + j] = 1){
                     if(sum == 3 || sum == 2){
                        array[(i * boardColSize) + j ] = 1;
                    }else{
                        array[(i * boardColSize) + j ] = 0;                 
                    }
                }else if (board[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 0){
                    if(sum == 3){
                        array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 1;
                    }else{
                        array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 0;                  
                    }           
                }           
            }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++){
            board[i * boardColSize + j] = array[i * boardColSize + j];
            printf("%d",board[i * boardColSize + j]);

    }
}

}
```

it should be assumed that the function countLiveNeighbor() works as intended counting the correct amount of alive neighbors.

this is what the array looks like

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001000000000000
00000000000000000000010100000000000
00000000000000000000111110000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000100010000000000
00000000000000000001100011000000000
00000000000000000010100010100000000
00000000000000000001100011000000000
00000000000000000000100010000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000111110000000000
00000000000000000000010100000000000
00000000000000000000001000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
```

CountLiveNeighbor function

```
int countLiveNeighbor(int* board, int boardRowSize, int boardColSize, int row, int col){
    int count = 0;  
    if((row - 1) >= 0 && board[ (row -1) * boardColSize + (col)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((row + 1) < boardRowSize  && board[ (row + 1) * boardColSize + (col)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((col - 1) >= 0 && board[ (row) * boardColSize + (col - 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((col - 1) < boardColSize && board[ (row) * boardColSize + (col + 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((row - 1) >= 0  && (col - 1) >= 0 && board[  (row -1) * boardColSize + (col - 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((row + 1) < boardRowSize  && (col - 1) >= 0 &&  board[(row + 1) * boardColSize + (col - 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((row + 1) < boardRowSize  && (col + 1) < boardColSize &&  board[(row + 1) * boardColSize + (col + 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }if((row - 1) >= 0  && (col + 1) < boardColSize &&  board[(row - 1) * boardColSize + (col + 1)] == 1){
        count++;    
    }
    return count;


}
```

> **provided is the function used to test this program:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "updateBoard.h"
#include "updateBoardGold.h"

int main(){
    int row,col,step;
    step = 0;
    row = 18;
    col = 35;
    int i,j;
    int game_board_stu[18*35] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int game_board_gold[18*35] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
    int stuCount,goldCount;
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){
            stuCount = countLiveNeighbor(game_board_stu, row, col, i, j);
            goldCount = countLiveNeighbor_gold(game_board_gold,row,col,i,j);
            if(stuCount != goldCount){
                printf("countLiveNeighbor test failed\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("countLiveNeighbor test passed\n");
    step = 0;
    while(!aliveStable_gold(game_board_gold, row, col)){
        if(step > 10000){
            printf("updateBoard test passed\n");
            printf("aliveStable test not finished due to too many steps taken\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if(aliveStable(game_board_stu,row,col)){
            printf("aliveStable test failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
        updateBoard_gold(game_board_gold,row,col);
        updateBoard(game_board_stu,row,col);
        for(i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(game_board_stu[i*col+j]!= game_board_gold[i*col+j]){
                    printf("updateBoard test failed\n");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!aliveStable(game_board_stu,row,col)){
        printf("aliveStable test failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("updateBoard test passed\n");
    printf("aliveStable test passed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this line to do?  array[(i * boardColSize) + j] == board[(i * boardColSize) + j];  It just compares the two array elements and doesn't do anything.

Comment: @bruceg I wanted to input whatever was in the board array's place inside the new array

Comment: you probably want to change "==" to "=".  Change your comparison to an assignment and see if that helps.

Comment: it does help, however, I guess that wasn't the problem as the board values still aren't changing according to the game of life rules @bruceg

Comment: [Edit] Your question and provide a [MCVE]. Then maybe someone is willing to help you to debug your code.

Comment: @muro0814 please show a [MCVE]. Something I can copy/paste into my IDE and compile and theen run it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I provided a way for you to test the functions

Comment: @muro0814 `aliveStable_gold`, `aliveStable_gold`, `countLiveNeighbor_gold` and `updateBoard_gold` are still missing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the aliveStable and countLiveNeighbor golds aren't required for this problem, I was not provided with updateBoard_gold

Comment: @muro0814 maybe they are not requires for this problem, but they are required so I can compile and run the program here on my computer whithout doing guesswork. That's why I asked for a [mcve], emphasis on Minimal and Complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to initialize array variable and replace "==" to "=" as it was mentioned already.
Here is your code I tried to edit. You can edit it further as per your needs.

```
void updateBoard(int* board, int boardRowSize, int boardColSize) {
int i, j, sum, k;
k = boardRowSize * boardColSize;
int array[20];
memset(array, 0, k*sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++) {
        array[(i * boardColSize) + j] == board[(i * boardColSize) + j];
        printf("%d", array[i * boardColSize + j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
for (i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++) {
        sum = 0;
        sum = countLiveNeighbor(board, boardRowSize, boardColSize, i, j);
        if (board[i * boardColSize + j] == 1) {
            if (sum == 3 || sum == 2) {
                array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 1;
            }
            else {
                array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (board[(i * boardColSize) + j] == 0) {
            if (sum == 3) {
                array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 1;
            }
            else {
                array[(i * boardColSize) + j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < boardRowSize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < boardColSize; j++) {
        board[i * boardColSize + j] = array[i * boardColSize + j];
        printf("%d", board[i * boardColSize + j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an infinite loop error when attempting compile this, I'm also unfamiliar with what memset does

Comment: memset fills given memory location with given value. In this case it fills array variable with 0. This code works fine for me when I have hardcoded sum as 3 or 2. Where are you getting infinite loop? Is it related to countLiveNeighbor?

Comment: I don't think its because of countLiveNeighbor but I'll add it for you to check